# How to find string but do not start with using regular expression

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

i want to change my code with CTRL+Replace by using regular expression in VS IDE.

("  replacing to  (L"

There are following lines in my code :

```
SetData("ABCDEFG"); // I want to change SetData(L"ABCDEFG")
a = "(";            // I don't want to change
```

how can i do that in regular expression.

i can write this :

```
\( *"
```

but this is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a look ahead. The simplest would be:

```
\("(?=.*")
```

If your code can contain multiple pairs of quotes per line, you need:

```
\("(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\((?="[^;\s])
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/17